# How to format a json data with dynamic variable using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am preparing a json data dynamically in Python meaning pass_over can change
anytime. I just provided an example below which makes it fixed
Each time I pass tester variable to an api call all i get is

valueError: invalid format specifier

Here is my code

```
    pass_over = '000067895'

    tester = f'''{
              "custId": {pass_over},
              "acctStatusCriterion": [
                {
                  "acctType": "YY",
                  "acctStatus": "Open"
                },
                {
                  "acctType": "VV",
                  "acctStatus": "Open"
                },
              ],
              "incExtAcctInfoFlag": true 
            }'''
```

What am i doing wrong? can't I use the f string in python. Is this json format not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the brackets (all of them), the f string considers what's inside them a variable (they are used as format specifiers) and not only the one with the variable you intend to change. To solve this, use double brackets in all the ones you wish to ignore, like :

```
pass_over = '000067895'

tester = f'''{{
            "custId": '{pass_over}',
            "acctStatusCriterion": [
            {{
                "acctType": "YY",
                "acctStatus": "Open"
            }},
            {{
                "acctType": "VV",
                "acctStatus": "Open"
            }},
            ],
            "incExtAcctInfoFlag": true 
        }}'''

print(tester)
```

output:

```
    {
        "custId": '000067895',
        "acctStatusCriterion": [
        {
            "acctType": "YY",
            "acctStatus": "Open"
        },
        {
            "acctType": "VV",
            "acctStatus": "Open"
        },
        ],
        "incExtAcctInfoFlag": true
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting custId from another function and noticed that if I manually do this  "custPermId": "0000459889", in the json file  everything works but if I do "custId": {pass_over}, it does not work. I am passing this json data to an api as a body.

Comment: did you try  changing brackets to double brackets as i said  except for the brackets around the pass_over ?

Comment: I changed everything to double brackets

Comment: you should keep single brackets around your variables (check the example I gave you)

Comment: "custPermId": {custPermId},  Yes I do

Comment: and it doesn t work ?? if so can you share the error ?

Comment: This line here "custId": 000067895, is meant to be "custId": "000067895", There has to be quotes for the value otherwise it will not work . Tested with postman

Comment: When passed to my api it is returning an internal server error. How can you add double quotes to the value of custPermId?

Comment: ah! now I get your point, then do this it ll solve it : `"custId": '{pass_over}',` (added '' before the brackets, check the edit for the new output)